# Compare first column of 2 files based on the second column using the delimiter ;

Tags: text-processing, files, awk, scripting, merge

I need to compare below 2 files.

The `head_file`:

```
    2345;int builder(
    1000;char type::edit::display <test>(
    250;void unamed_string_tree*
```

The `ref_file`:

```
    2000;int builder(
    500;char type::edit::display <test>(
    3000;fillTest*(
```

Desired output:

```
FUNCTION,HEAD,REF,DIFF
int builder(,2345,2000,-345
char type::edit::display <test>(,1000,500,-500
void unamed_string_tree*,250,0,-250
fillTest*(,0,3000,3000
```

Comment: where does the "-245" cames from? What have you tried?

Comment: @JJoao I think it's a typo, I is meant -345...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN{OFS=",";
  print "FUNCTION,HEAD,REF,DIFF"}
  FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}
  {print $2,$1,a[$2]*1,a[$2]-$1; delete a[$2]}
  END{for (i in a){print i,0,a[i],a[i]}}' ref_file head_file
```

---

**The explanation**:

- `-F";"` specifies the semicolon `;` as delimiter.
- The `BEGIN{...}` rule is executed once only, before the first input record is read. In that rule, the `OFS` (output field separator) is set to comma `,` and the header line is printed: `FUNCTION,HEAD,REF,DIFF`.
- `FNR==NR` applies for the first file being processed: the `ref_file`.

  - `a[$2]=$1;next` The files contents are now stored in an array called `a` with the index `$2` and the value `$1`.
- {...} that block applies for every line of the second file, the `head_file`:

  - `print ...` the values are printed with the corresponding value in the previously created array. Notice `[$2]*1`; when the value is empty the multiplication with `*1` ends in a zero `0`.
  - `delete a[$2]`: When finished delete the array element.
- The `END{...}` rule is executed once only, after the last input record is read.

  - `for (i in a)`: Loop trough the rest of the array `a` which is not yet deleted.
  - `print ...`: Print its indexes and values.

---

**The output**:

```
FUNCTION,HEAD,REF,DIFF
int builder(,2345,2000,-345
char type::edit::display <test>(,1000,500,-500
void unamed_string_tree*,250,0,-250
fillTest*(,0,3000,3000
```

Comment: It worked properly but using **nawk** and not awk. Is there a way not to display functions having REF=HEAD=0 ? @chaos

Comment: I found the solution. `nawk -F";" 'BEGIN{OFS=","; print "FUNCTION,HEAD,REF,DIFF"} FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next} {if ($1 != 0) {print $2,$1,a[$2]*1,a[$2]-$1} ; delete a[$2]} END{for (i in a){if (a[i] != 0) print i,0,a[i],a[i]}}' ref_file head_file`